# How do I use custom SQL in sprint data repository?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I`m using Repository like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<User> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(String emailAddress, String lastname);
}
```

But what I need is execute my own `sql statement`.

```
select u.* from users u where exists ( select 1 from expires_users where users_id = u.id )
```

Please, past link references in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do as pointed in the [documentation of Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

Here is an example:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  @Query("select u.* from User u 
          where exists(select 1 from ExpiredUser e where e.id = u.id)")
  Page<User> findExpiredUsers(Pageable pageable);
}
```

The **Page** and **Pageable** parts are for paging results, assuming that this query could return many more results than you would like to process at once. More information on paging results can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result).